# Taking too much time in indexing while integrating nutch 2.3, Hbase and Solr

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, lucene, nutch

**I am integrating Nutch,Hbase and Solr** .

*I configured Nutch, Hbase and Solr and also did operation for Crawling the Websites* but while integrating the Nutch with Solr by following this 
[Integrating Nutch 2.3, HBase and Solr](http://www.lostinsoftware.com/2015/11/integrating-nutch-2-3-hbase-and-solr/), I executed the command 
**java jar start.jar**  in  **/opt/solr-4.8.1/examples**.

The process is started but **it is taking so much time for execution about 10 days and** still now it's running.

I am unable to find out what is going wrong with it. 
Can anyone suggest what's the problem and how to solve.

Below are few details of logs file.

```
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:00.286; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; start commit{,optimize=true,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:00.287; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; No uncommitted changes. Skipping IW.commit.
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:00.287; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; SolrIndexSearcher has not changed - not re-opening: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:00.288; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; end_commit_flush
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:00.288; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitFlush=true&optimize=true&wt=json&_=1463567280272} {optimize=} 0 2
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:01.976; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; start commit{,optimize=true,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:01.976; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; No uncommitted changes. Skipping IW.commit.
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:01.977; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; SolrIndexSearcher has not changed - not re-opening: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:01.977; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; end_commit_flush
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:01.978; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitFlush=true&optimize=true&wt=json&_=1463567281965} {optimize=} 0 2
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:05.799; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/threads params={wt=json&_=1463567285780} status=0 QTime=8 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:09.267; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/properties params={wt=json&_=1463567289183} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:11.225; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={wt=json&_=1463567291213} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:11.260; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={wt=json&_=1463567291242} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:13.808; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/luke params={show=index&numTerms=0&wt=json&_=1463567293791} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:13.821; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1463567293794} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:13.837; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=json&_=1463567293796} status=0 QTime=4 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:13.845; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/file/ params={file=admin-extra.html&_=1463567293798} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 15:58:13.856; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={action=status&wt=json&_=1463567293801} status=503 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:35.235; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/logging params={wt=json&since=0&_=1463570675193} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:38.820; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1463570678769} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:38.821; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/luke params={show=index&numTerms=0&wt=json&_=1463570678764} status=0 QTime=2 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:38.823; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={action=status&wt=json&_=1463570678776} status=503 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:38.829; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/file/ params={file=admin-extra.html&_=1463570678774} status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:38.831; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=json&_=1463570678772} status=0 QTime=11 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:46.728; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/mbeans params={stats=true&wt=json&_=1463570686705} status=0 QTime=5 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:49.533; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/mbeans params={stats=true&wt=json&_=1463570689477} status=0 QTime=3 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:54:52.762; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1463570692692} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:33.180; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/logging params={wt=json&since=0&_=1463570793166} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:38.195; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/luke params={show=index&numTerms=0&wt=json&_=1463570798128} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:38.198; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1463570798132} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:38.199; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={action=status&wt=json&_=1463570798137} status=503 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:38.201; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/file/ params={file=admin-extra.html&_=1463570798135} status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2016-05-18 16:56:38.211; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=json&_=1463570798133} status=0 QTime=12
```

Comment: Wow, how can you wait for 10 days for something ...

Comment: I started work on other stuff and leave the integration process as it is.

Comment: You can check the log of solr to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah i checked logs,each and every time Solr performing some Operations like  **org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=json&_=1463570798133} status=0 QTime=12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I resolved it.
Basically, **java -jar start.jar** downloads the jar files,so it is not doing indexing here but downloading the Solr 4.8 jars and then configuring it.I replaced Solr 4.8 with Solr 5.2.1 due to performance and now Solr working fine.